# Not able to create eloquent relationship with table which have custom primary key

Tags: laravel, relationship, eloquent

When i'm trying to get user details from company Model i'm getting NULL value.

```
class User extends Model
{
  protected $primaryKey = 'uid';
}


class Company extends Model
{
   $table = 'company';

   public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\User','user_id','uid');
   }
}
```

class RepoController{

```
public function index(){
  $user = Company::where('id',1)->with('user')->get(); 
  /// Returning value but without Users
  } 
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`users` table should contain `company_id` and you should define `id` as company ID because `company` table doesn't use custom ID:

```
public function users()
{
     return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'company_id', 'id');
}
```

Or just this:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

Also, you're trying to load `user` relationship, but it should be `users()`, so do this instead:

```
Company::where('id', 1)->with('users')->get();
```

Comment: sorry thats a typo its actually users

Comment: it didn't work but it work when change comment  // protected $primaryKey = 'uid';

Comment: when `$this->hasMany('App\User')` is executed, the system expects the id to be model name appended with `_id`. So it will be expecting `user_id` to be present in both the models

Comment: Thanks for support i figure out by matching keys

Comment: @CerlinBoss not exactly. Since it's `hasMany()`, Laravel will look for only `company_id` in the `users` table.

Answer (score 0):

I think your ids are in wrong position

try swapping them like

```
return $this->hasMany('App\User','uid','user_id');
```